# How to do fast search on 15 million records

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have excel file of 600 records, which I am going to compare with 15 million records from the database. For each excel record I need to find matches from 15 million records. currently it takes about 4 hours to complete the process. I want to minimize it at least up to 2 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Export excel to CSV
2. Import CSV into mysql (LOAD)
3. Create index on the key column (the one you want to compare with the 15M records)
4. Make sure that the 15M records table has the proper index set up on the comparison key!
5. Write a simple query that joins the two table with the criteria you need.

All these points are fairly trivial and left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I am using 5 columns to search the data. how it is going to help me if i import csv into mysql, actually the next step will be to write matched data into excel file. Currently I am using PHP to read each record and comparing it with 15 Million records

Comment: It is going to help you because internal mysql search is millions of times faster than looping through a file, then php, then mysql. You are trying to eat soup using a fork, with your current method. I am showing you a spoon. Make an attempt, before dismissing what I am saying.

Comment: And, as you can import data in mysql, you can export it to CSV and do the process in reverse.

Comment: okay thanks for your suggestion  I will do the necessary changes

Answer (score 2):

Try

**if indexing not done** : 
Do indexing across the fields you are comparing, the result would be magical.

if possible avoid using LIKE queries and change the sequence of WHERE query.

eg: `WHERE city = "New York" AND name LIKE "XYZ" AND mobile=7777777777 AND status=1`

it should be like

```
WHERE status=1 AND mobile=7777777777 AND city = "New York" AND name LIKE "XYZ"
```

SEQUENCE of where flags then ints then chars then varchars then like in last, it matters a lot.

Comment: Let me try this. i have very odd sequence. thanks for the suggetion